# Dropzonejs cannot submit properly

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

Here is my dropzone config:

```js
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".myDZ", {
    url: $('#form').attr('action'), 
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    uploadMultiple: true, 
    previewsContainer: "#previews", 
    clickable: "#fileinput-btn", 
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function() {
        var dz = this;
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dz.processQueue();
        });
    }
});
```

After the submit button is pressed, I can see from the backend that the data was submitted correctly. However, after the backend returns a response, the front end will not react to it. The form page stays the same without displaying the returned message and clicking on the submit button again will not trigger any submit.

I tried this:

```
this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dz.processQueue();
            document.getElementById("form").submit();
        });
    }
});
```

This will force the form to submit twice but display the correct response after the 2nd attempt. This works but feels wrong.

Any suggestions on what might went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree that submitting it twice is kind of dirty.
You might try to catch your response in a success function because Dropzone is waiting asynchronously.

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone(".myDZ", {
    url: $('#form').attr('action'), 
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    uploadMultiple: true, 
    previewsContainer: "#previews", 
    clickable: "#fileinput-btn", 
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    init: function() {
        var dz = this;
        this.element.querySelector("button[type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            dz.processQueue();
        });
    },
    // Try this success.
    success: function (data, response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: Great, thx! I did get the response back. I guess I will have to handle the response using javascript. Thanks!